# It is possible use AutoScaling with Elastic Mapreduce?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I would like to know if I can use AutoScaling to automatically scaling up or down Amazon Ec2 capacity according to cpu utilization with elastic map reduce.

For example, I start a mapreduce job with only 1 instance, but if this instance arrive to 50% utilization for example I want to use the created AutoScaling group to start a new instance. This is possible?

Do you know if it is possible? Or elastic mapreduce because is "elastic", if it needs starts automatically more instances without any configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Auto Scaling cannot be used with Amazon Elastic MapReduce (EMR).

It is possible to scale EMR via API or Command-Line calls, adding and removing Task Nodes (which do not host HDFS storage). Note that it is not possible to remove Core Nodes (because they host HDFS storage, and removing nodes could lead to lost data). In fact, this is the only difference between Core and Task nodes.

It is also possible to change the number of nodes from within an EMR "Step". Steps are executed sequentially, so the cluster could be made larger prior to a step requiring heavy processing, and could be reduced in size in a subsequent step.

From the [EMR Developer Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-manage-resize.html):

> You can have a different number of slave nodes for each cluster step. You can also add a step to a running cluster to modify the number of slave nodes. Because all steps are guaranteed to run sequentially by default, you can specify the number of running slave nodes for any step.

CPU would not be a good metric on which to base scaling of an EMR cluster, since Hadoop will keep all nodes as busy as possible when a job is running. A better metric would be the number of jobs waiting, so that they can finish quicker.

See also:

- Stackoverflow: [Can we add more Amazon Elastic Mapreduce instances into an existing Amazon Elastic Mapreduce instances?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10449300/can-we-add-more-amazon-elastic-mapreduce-instances-into-an-existing-amazon-elast)
- Stackoverflow: [Can Amazon Auto Scaling Service work with Elastic Map Reduce Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955822/can-amazon-auto-scaling-service-work-with-elastic-map-reduce-service)

Answer (score 2):

You need Qubole: http://www.qubole.com/blog/product/industrys-first-auto-scaling-hadoop-clusters/

We have never seen any of our users/customers use vanilla auto-scaling successfully with Hadoop. Hadoop is stateful. Nodes hold HDFS data and intermediate outputs. Deleting nodes based on cpu/memory just doesn't work. Adding nodes needs sophistication - this isn't a web site. One needs to look at the sizes of jobs submitted and the speed at which they are completing.

We run the largest Hadoop clusters, easily, on AWS (for our customers). And they auto-scale all the time. And they use spot instances. And it costs the same as EMR.